# MC exiled from kingdom for ostensibly poisoning a duke. Becomes an S-Rank Adventurer

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't remember any of the big things that happen only this

manga where the mc is exiled out of the kingdom for poisoning a duke but he didn't do it so he goes to the closest kingdom and becomes an s-rank adventurer because of his class which is highly sought after because he can upgrade items

Comment: What does "S-Rank" mean?

Comment: @JonB: The standard Japanese ranking system has [S as a level above A](https://www.33rdsquare.com/why-is-rank-s-higher-than-a/) with them sometimes adding S+, SS, SSS, etc.